# How to add time delay to div when display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wants to add read more button to the content in HTML and when click that button it should display hidden div and display none the read more button. I did it, but now i wants to do that smoothly. i want to add time delay to that hidden div when display.

This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>nhlkhlhlib;b</h3>
    <p>hjglhvlgugyjlbljg</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 add-margin-bottom">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <button class="btn-read-more" id="read-one">READ MORE</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding" id="para-one">
       <p>hgkjhfkuyfkvkkviyftyff</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

when click the `id=read-one` button. it display the `id="para-one"`.

this is the java script i used.

```
$( '.btn-read-more' ).click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id=="read-one"){
            $("#read-one").css("display","none");
            $("#para-one").css("display","block");
            });
});
```

so i want to add time delay to this click action.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: setTimeout? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout Do you need a simple delay or a smarter animation?

Comment: Do you want a time delay, or a smooth-looking transition while the additional information shows? If it's the latter, then I'd recommend looking into `CSS` transitions. A timer won't prevent it from suddenly jolting into view.

Comment: Look at [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Answer (score 2):

### How about a pure CSS solution?*

The core thing here is that you cannot transition/animate on `display` as it is a binary/non ordinal property. You will need to transition on either `height`, or `max-height`. The reason being in e.g. your use-case, `display` is either `none` or `block`, what would the intermediary values be? As `height` and `max-height` are unit based values, intermediary values can be calculated as a function of amount over time.

Although this can be accomplished in javascript, writing the style change within CSS keeps the **strict separation of concerns** between content (HTML), function (JS) and style (CSS). Although a pure CSS solution is likely not appropriate, it gives you an idea of how this can be done. In your javascript, instead of defining the transition/style, you can then simply toggle a class on the element in question, *see the second example below for a javascript implementation.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 300ms, opacity 200ms;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + p {
  max-height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="read-more">READ MORE</label>
  <input id="read-more" type='checkbox' />
  <p>some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

### Javascript Alternative

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('p').toggleClass('expand');
});
```

```css
    p {

      overflow: hidden;

      opacity: 0;

      max-height: 0;

      transition: max-height 300ms, opacity 200ms;

    }

    p.expand {

      max-height: 150px;

      opacity: 1;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>READ MORE</button>
  <p>some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />some text content
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi i have do it simple and smoothly with fadeIn() and fadeOut() you can try the snippet code check it out

```js
$("#para-one").hide();
$( '.btn-read-more' ).click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(id=="read-one"){
            $("#read-one").fadeOut("fast",function(){
            $("#para-one").delay(300).fadeIn("fast");
            });
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>nhlkhlhlib;b</h3>
    <p>hjglhvlgugyjlbljg</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 add-margin-bottom">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <button class="btn-read-more" id="read-one">READ MORE</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding" id="para-one">
        <p>hgkjhfkuyfkvkkviyftygfgf<br>sdvdvdvsdvff<br>fdfdfdfdfdf</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .fadeIn and .fadeOut with .delay of jquery:

```
$('.btn-read-more').click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
if (id=="read-one"){
    $("#read-one").fadeOut('fast');
    $("#para-one").delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

});

See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bm0yv8o3/

Answer (score 0):

who gave this answer? it works correctly. Unfortunately he removed his answer. Anyway thanks a lot who try to help me.

```
$( '.btn-read-more' ).click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id=="read-one") {
                $("#read-one").hide(300, function () {
                    $("#para-one").show(300);
                });
         }
    });
```

[this is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/kw5awpt5/)